# Difficulty establishing Bulk Transfer In USB Driver

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, usb, driver, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to send `BULK` data using `BULK` end point. But each time I submit the `URB`, it never fires the `URB Callback` function until I disconnect the device. Once I disconnect, it fires the callback throwing an `EPROTO` error. Anyone faced similar condition? Am I doing something incorrectly? I'm sure my device and data cable is okay. Here goes my code. Please suggest possible solution

```
static void urb_received(struct urb *urb)
{
    printk("URB Received\n");

    switch (urb->status) {
    case 0:
        printk("case SUCCESS\n");
        break;
    case -ETIMEDOUT:
        printk("case ETIMEDOUT\n");
        return;
    case -ENOENT:
        printk("case ENONET\n");
        return;
    case -EPROTO:
        printk("case EPROTO\n");
        return;
    case -ECONNRESET:
        printk("case ECONNRESET\n");
        return;
    case -ESHUTDOWN:
        printk("case ESHUTDOWN\n");
        return;
    default:
        printk("unknown urb status %i\n", urb->status);
    }
    printk("URB Received Exit\n");
}

static int myprobe(struct usb_interface *intf,
    const struct usb_device_id *id)
{
    static int intfcount = 0;
    int ret = 0;
    int i;
    struct device *dev = &intf->dev;
    struct mydevice *mydev;
    struct usb_device *usb_dev = interface_to_usbdev(intf);
    struct usb_host_interface *interface_descriptor;
    struct usb_endpoint_descriptor *endpoint;

    if (id->idVendor == MY_DEVICE_ID && id->idProduct == MY_PRODUCT_ID){
        interface_descriptor = intf->cur_altsetting;

        mydev = kzalloc(sizeof(struct mydev), GFP_KERNEL);
        mydev->dev = dev;
        mydev->udev = usb_get_dev(interface_to_usbdev(intf));


        interface_descriptor = intf->cur_altsetting;


        for(i=0; i<interface_descriptor->desc.bNumEndpoints; i++){
            endpoint = &interface_descriptor->endpoint[i].desc;

            if (((endpoint->bEndpointAddress & USB_ENDPOINT_DIR_MASK) == USB_DIR_OUT) && 
                (endpoint->bmAttributes & USB_ENDPOINT_XFERTYPE_MASK) == USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK
               ){
                    printk("MEDEV: Bulk out endpoint");
                    mydev->bulk_out_endpointAddr = endpoint->bEndpointAddress;
                    break;
                }
        }

        bulk_urb = usb_alloc_urb(0, GFP_ATOMIC);
        bulk_urb->transfer_buffer = kzalloc(8, GFP_ATOMIC);
        usb_fill_bulk_urb(bulk_urb, usb_dev, usb_sndbulkpipe(mydev->udev, endpoint->bEndpointAddress),
            bulk_urb->transfer_buffer, 8,
            urb_received, NULL);
        printk("BULK OUT PIPE = %d\n", mydev->bulk_out_pipe);

        ret = usb_submit_urb(bulk_urb, GFP_ATOMIC);

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Just found out one interesting & same time annoying thing.

If in the above code I declare the `usb_fill_bulk_urb` with `buffer_length=4`, then it works perfectly. I can get the data from my android device. Even though I'm creating a buffer size of 8 bytes, I can't use `buffer_length=8`. I also played with other number but seems it only works for `buffer_length=4`.

To be sure I checked the endpoint descriptor of my device using `lsusb -v` command which shows it has a capacity of `512 bytes`. Also in my android app, I've taken care off how many bytes I want to read. There is nothing wrong with the android app. I just can't understand why I won't be able to send more than 4 bytes at a time. By the way, if I send less than 4 bytes, that also works.

Comment: What evidence to you have that your device and cable are OK?

Comment: because I used the same device for another driver which also sends and receives bulk data without a problem. I was trying to check with that solution and I don't see what I'm doing wrong. I'm confused because I think my code is correct.

Comment: This is likely to be influenced by the behaviour of the device's firmware. What does the other driver do differently?

Comment: The only difference is the other driver don't do it inside the probe function.

Comment: added some new findings in my question.

Comment: Ask whoever wrote the device's firmware why it doesn't accept bigger packets …

Comment: So finally I found that if the chunk size by which I read the data from the endpoint is not equal to the chunk size by which data is being transferred, the error occurs. So if I transfer data by 16 bytes, and try to read by 8 bytes, the urb_complete function will get called and will raise the error. But if I transfer by 16 bytes and read by 16 bytes, it works without a problem